# Como alterar tema do Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto, um site e nele eu tenho um mapa escuro do Google Maps, é um mapa comum com uma coordenada especifica de Latitude e Longitude, mas gostaria que este meu mapa fosse dinâmico e com outro tema, exemplo: tema azul, com a possibilidade de usar o recurso do streetview, com controle do zoom na lateral do mapa, tenho esse código:

```js
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});

//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});


var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.385873, -1.471471),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    styles: [{
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 17
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 20
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 17
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 29
        }, {
            "weight": 0.2
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 18
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 16
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 21
        }]
    }, {
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "on"
        }, {
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 16
        }]
    }, {
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": 36
        }, {
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 40
        }]
    }, {
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 19
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 20
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 17
        }, {
            "weight": 1.2
        }]
    }]
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
```

```css
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- Google Maps API Key - You will need to use your own API key to use the map feature -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

 <!-- Core JavaScript Files -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Veja se algo aqui o pode ajudar https://snazzymaps.com/

Comment: Dê uma olhada http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251738/detecting-google-maps-streetview-mode

Comment: No site [Snazzy Maps](https://snazzymaps.com/) tem vários temas disponíveis para você utilizar.

Answer (score 4):

Remova a propriedade `disableDefaultUI: true` pois ela é responsável por desabilitar as funções que citou: recurso do `street view` com controle de zoom na lateral do mapa.

E quanto ao tema, não está muito clara a sua dúvida mas se estiver procurando usar a aparência "padrão" do Google, basta remover o *array* `styles` das suas configurações do mapa.

Removi o código desnecessário do seu *snippet*, ficando assim:

```js
var options = {
  zoom: 15,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.385873, -1.471471),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
```

```css
body, html, #map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```